# What happens when I press enter in console? JS

Tags: javascript

If I write a 'test' string in console and press enter, is that string saved in memory even though I haven't assigned it to a variable? Also does the same principle apply to other primitives.. how about doing this:

['test'] press enter;

{test: 'test'} press enter

Comment: No, it's just a string. What is your question?

Comment: Those string representation, array representation and object representation are called expressions. When you enter an expression, it will be evaluated. But since you do not assign it to variable, it will just be evaluated and discarded. More info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console will execute the code you put into the command line and after the execution, it will run a console.log of the latest statement written in the global scope, if it doesn't contain any var, let, const declaration, variable assignation etc, a just raw statement to be logged.

Bearing that in mind, the memory allocation will work only for executable code, not for this last line which is more for debugging.

```
> var x = 1; //allocated in memory
> x
// 1

> {test: 'test'} // not allocated in memory
// {test: "test"} (in expandable format)
```

Comment: Except that the console application itself keeps a reference to all the objects that it displayed.

Comment: Yes but still not part of the js execution heap or stack at all.

Comment: The question isn't that specific.